# raphael svg import size

Tags: javascript, svg, size, raphael, scale

I've created and SVG-file from an Illustrator-image. I'm using this: https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import to import and display the vector-image.

I read the svg-file in as text, and submit it to the import-function:

```
var mygetrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var svgdata = mygetrequest.responseText; 
paper.importSVG(svgdata); //where paper is my Raphael canvas
```

All working very nicely.

But I can't seem to find any info or hints on how to change the settings and view of the image? 
For example I would very much like it to fill out its container, disregarding the size of this.

Any ideas? Documentation to help me along the way? Anything, really...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ideas I can offer you:

1) *maybe* the SVG import takes into account the original size and does scaling for you. However when editing in illustrator you *might* have a much bigger document around it, which confuses the svgImport?

2) Otherwise, you could import the paper as a set. And scale the set.

```
var set = paper.set();
paper.importSVG(svgdata, set);
set.scale( 2, 2, centerx, centery );
```

(I'm not sure without an example to play with, what centerx and centery should be).

[EDIT (after approval)]
It seems Raphael enables you to get a set's bounding box:

```
var bbox = set.getBBox();
// You'll now have bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width and bbox.height at your disposal. 
// For example:
paper.rect( bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height ).attr('border', 'red');
```

So I'd say you could:

1. Get bounding box of imported SVG set
2. Use `set.translate` to align the bounding box's center with the center of the paper (use something like `( paperwidth / 2 ) - ( bbox.x + bbox.width / 2 )` for example for the x translation).
3. Scale based on the bounding box size compared to the paper size. You probably want to scale while maintaining aspect ratio so you'll have to use the one that's closest to `1` (of 
   `paper.width/bbox.width` and `paper.height/bbox.height`).
4. (Note: use center of paper now as center of scaling - since you translated your set this is actually the center of the svg set as well)

I did this from the top of my head so it might not be 100% accurate, but if you get the idea you'll probably be able to get rid of the glitches.

Comment: @1 - none the less, correcting this doesn't allow me to change the appearance in the different containers. 
But 2 does. I have a feeling that this isn't the most convenient way to get around the issue, but for now it works and I'm happy!

Comment: Great to be of help. The problem that makes a 'straightforward' solution not so obvious is the question what is the size of a svg. Apart from the document size, the only clue any software piece can have is the 'extremes' of the bounding boxes of the individual svg elements. I have some ideas about making this a little bit more universal and will post them as EDIT in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I did was open the SVG in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (SVG editor program), change the size until it was OK... but there is probably a better way!

Comment: That would kind of ruin the whole purpose of the SVG, since it is meant to be used several place in different scalings. Thanks for the input, though!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as the original poster. I was doing the same thing that he did. I came across problems that I was not able to solve for days even after I read the solution/ideas from Jochem.

My specific problem was that in Internet Explorer (all versions), the image kept rendering out of bounds, specifically aligning itself to the bottom right hand corner of the containing div.

- Trying to center and 'fit' the image to it's container using transformations did not work nor was it easy to understand the Raphael's implementation of the transformations.
- I've realized that raphael-svg-import library was incomplete, unable to work with svg groups and documentation are non-existent.

After spending so much time on this issue, my senior developer concluded that this plugin is flawed and is unusable.

So far, I have not been able to find a alternative solution that meets my specific requirements (we cannot use Flash because of company policies). For those without that constrain, I recommend Google's [SVGWeb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)

Although this is not a answer to the OP's question, my findings may save some time for someone who might come across this issue in the future.